# Quaternions getting warped or flickers

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions, glm-math

I am trying to create my own quaternion class and I get weird results. Either the cube I am trying to rotate is flickering like crazy, or it is getting warped.

This is my code:

```
void Quaternion::AddRotation(vec4 v)
{
    Quaternion temp(v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
    *this = temp * (*this);
}

mat4   Quaternion::GenerateMatrix(Quaternion &q)
{
    q.Normalize();

    //Row order
    mat4 m( 1 - 2*q.y*q.y - 2*q.z*q.z, 2*q.x*q.y - 2*q.w*q.z, 2*q.x*q.z + 2*q.w*q.y, 0,
            2*q.x*q.y + 2*q.w*q.z, 1 - 2*q.x*q.x - 2*q.z*q.z, 2*q.y*q.z + 2*q.w*q.x, 0,
            2*q.x*q.z - 2*q.w*q.y, 2*q.y*q.z - 2*q.w*q.x, 1 - 2*q.x*q.x - 2*q.y*q.y, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);

    //Col order
    //  mat4 m( 1 - 2*q.y*q.y - 2*q.z*q.z,2*q.x*q.y + 2*q.w*q.z,2*q.x*q.z - 2*q.w*q.y,0,
    //          2*q.x*q.y - 2*q.w*q.z,1 - 2*q.x*q.x - 2*q.z*q.z,2*q.y*q.z - 2*q.w*q.x,0,
    //          2*q.x*q.z + 2*q.w*q.y,2*q.y*q.z + 2*q.w*q.x,1 - 2*q.x*q.x - 2*q.y*q.y,0,
    //          0,0,0,1);

    return m;
}
```

When I create the entity I give it a quaternion:

```
entity->Quat.AddRotation(vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 45.f));
```

And each frame I try to rotate it additionally by a small amount:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Entities.size(); i++)
{
    if (Entities[i] != NULL)
    {
        Entities[i]->Quat.AddRotation(vec4(0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f, 0.000005f));
        Entities[i]->DrawModel();
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

And finally this is how I draw each cube:

```
void Entity::DrawModel()
{
    glPushMatrix();

    //Rotation
    mat4 RotationMatrix;
    RotationMatrix = this->Quat.GenerateMatrix(this->Quat);

    //Position
    mat4 TranslationMatrix = glm::translate(mat4(1.0f), this->Pos);

    this->Trans = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix;

    glMultMatrixf(value_ptr(this->Trans));

    if (this->shape != NULL)
        this->shape->DrawShape();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

**EDIT:** This is the tutorial I used to learn quaternions:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html

Comment: Then your code is wrong somewhere. Can you simplify your testcase and unit-test each of the quaternion methods? Try passing simple cases by hand and verify the edge-case correctness. Unfortunately there's no silver bullet here other than methodical and reasonable coding, most presumably with aforementioned TDD.

Comment: Yes, my code is not correct. I am not 100% sure I understand your answer, my english isn't the best... I have tried to keep it as basic as possible with only rendering a simple cube. I don't know how to set up an easier test case then that, sorry. This is all the code that I am using, regarding the quaternions. Thanks for response!

Comment: A simpler code wouldn't render anything, just calculate and output numbers on a very simple data you can verify yourself; you could also try to build equivalent transformations with matrices and quaternions (or even better, an other quaternion library you trust), and then check if the results are the same. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without studying your rotation matrix to the end, there are two possible bugs I can think of. The first one is that your rotation matrix R is not orthogonal, i.e. the inverse of R is not equal to the transposed. This could cause warping of the object. The second place to hide a bug is inside the multiplication of your quaternions.

Comment: I checked. The inverse != the transpose. Thanks for reminding me, I will look into the matter and hopefully find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in the rotation matrix. Try exchanging the element (2,3) with element (3,2).

Comment: This solved my flickering problem! Thanks! But now I ran into another problem... The object only rotates around its own Y-axis. I will look into the matter more. At least this is easier to debug then the flickering...